# if checks the data not inserting if inserting the data not checking.

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string strCon = "Server=yourServer;Database=BuspassDb;User Id=Sa;Password=india;";
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp", sqlConn);
            //cmd.CommandText = "CheckIfStringExists";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextTmp", txtString.Text);
            //SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            //param.ParameterName = "@TextTmp";
            //param.Value = txtString.Text;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    txtString.Text = (reader["Text"].ToString());
                    lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + ".... is already exists";
                }
                else 

                    lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "... is not exists";
                    txtString.Text = "";
                    sqlConn.Close();


                    //SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
                    //SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "InsertConsole2";
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextTmp", txtString.Text);
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "....is Inserted";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
It shows the following error on the page
```

What i am making wrong help please

if checks the data not inserting if inserting the data not checking

working if some one help its help full this question

```
> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

I am writing in C# then it is not working properly.
```

I am writing in C# then it is not working properly.

Comment: Just a heads up...  "It's not working" is not a good fit as a title.  How are future programmers going to know your issue may apply to them?

Comment: I have edited the title accordingly, as I think that's what you really meant to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866046/executereader-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 9):

change this line

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp",sqlConn );
```

also wrong parameter name change the statement of assigning parameter also

```
 param.ParameterName = "@TextTmp";
```

call executereader only once

Comment: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.   this is saying this error after that

Comment: i have added sqlconn in the this statement which u havent done

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the [`SqlCommand.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx).

You can pass it as the second parameter to an [alternate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx):

```
new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp", sqlConn);
```

or you can set the property directly:

```
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the SqlConnection in the SqlCommand. See this example :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp",sqlConn );
```

Check http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strCon = "Server=yourServer;Database=yourDB;User Id=Username;Password=Password;";
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp", sqlConn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextTmp", txtString.Text);

    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            txtString.Text = reader["Text"].ToString();
            lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + ": String is already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + ": No data";
             txtString.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: hi could you please tell me if it is not there data how to insert in to the data base to the same code

Comment: I did not understand you. Do you want me to create an insert query?

Comment: no i have the stored proc for insert from this code string is not there i need to insert that one

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code, including but not limited to:

- You are not assigning the `Connection` property of the `SqlCommand`.
- You are using the wrong parameter name (`@StringTmp` instead of `@TextTmp`).
- You are calling `ExecuteReader()` twice.
- You are not disposing objects properly. Use `using` blocks or call `Dispose()` yourself.

Also, you are effectively assigning `txtString.Text` to itself.

---

**EDIT:** Code sample

```
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Console where Text = @TextTmp", sqlConn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextTmp", txtString.Text);

            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        txtString.Text = reader["Text"].ToString(); // Why?
                        lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "String is already exists";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = txtString.Text + "No data";
                        txtString.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```