# asp.net and c# The full code is here

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i run it then it runs normally but when i input some data into the database through forms then it show the following error.

```
ExecuteNonQuery Connection property has not been initialized
```

And i have created the connection but yet it shows the error message.

```
using System;
public partial class Sign_Up : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection signupConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand signupcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_FirstName,Customer_LastName, Customer_Email, Customer_Password, Customer_Gender) VALUES (@fName,@lName,@Email,@Password,@Gender)");

            signupcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", txtfName.Text);
            signupcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", txtlName.Text);
            signupcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            signupcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            signupcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rdoGender.SelectedItem);

            try
            {
                signupConn.Open();
                signupcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Response.Write(err.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                signupConn.Close();
                signupConn.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866046/executereader-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: Despite your lack of formatting, the issue is that you're not assigning the `signupConn` to the `signupcmd`

Comment: you are not passing connection to the command object.

Comment: You have not linked your `SqlCommand` and your `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you aren't using the connection in your command, therefore the error.

The right SqlCommand constructor to use is `SqlCommand(string, SqlConnection)`, but you're just using `SqlCommand(string)`, like this:

```
SqlCommand signupcmd = new SqlCommand("you sql here", signupConn)
```

Anyway this is not the proper way to post a question on SO, bad formatting and poorly written. Please check the guidelines.

Comment: Don't forget you can close questions as unclear, too broad, lacking  proper description (what is it supposed to do)...